# Custom JWT based authentication for Google App Engine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, jwt

I am using Google App Engine with Java. 
I would like to know, how to integrate custom JWT based authentication in Google App Engine.

I have seen https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth  but I dont want the users connected with Google Account. I also want the users to sign in without an email address, but a username.

I searched on the internet but everywhere I looked, it is talking about the Google based authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at the example code at https://github.com/fabito/appengine-endpoints-jwt/tree/master ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can I find the documentation for the library?

Comment: I used to do JWT with Node.js. But there we could specify a middleware to verify the access token (I saw the JwtSecurityFilter class here, I tried putting log statements in all the three functions, but not coming.). Where is the JWT generation part?. can you provide code for login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems at the moment, there is no library available for doing this.
Also I was unable to find any documentation to do this.

Here is how I implemented it.

1. The client passes JWT in the Authorization header.
2. At the API endpoint (not in Filter, it wont work), I extracted the header and validated the JWT. I throws Exceptions from the validation function itself, so that I don't have to repeat a lot of code.