# Google App Engine Standard to App Engine Flex

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am new to Google App Engine services. I have a Java Maven project with one module running on app engine flex and other on app engine standard. I am using JWT authentication for App Engine Flex APIs. I want to make a post request from App Engine Standard to App Engine Flex. What should be the best way to authenticate the service?

Also, I have a cron service hitting a particular URL I am using for some backend stuff. How can I authenticate that the request has came from Cron service only?

Comment: Do not edit a question to transform it into an entirely new, unrelated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking if the job is coming from the Cron service (assuming you are using the `requests` module):

```
is_cron = request.headers.get('X-Appengine-Cron', False)
if not is_cron:
    return 'Bad Request', 400
```

If you are using another module, you just have to check the header from the cron job to make sure it is 'X-Appengine-Cron'

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#cron_requests

Comment: Thank you :)
I am still wondering how to authenticate request on app engine flex from app engine standard ?

Comment: You should be able to set permissions in the IAM & Admin section to allow one to speak to the other. Generally App Engine has good cross-functionality between products in terms of authentication.

Check these for more help (I'm not good with Maven):
https://github.com/fabito/appengine-endpoints-jwt/tree/master
https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started-appengine-standard/authenticate-users
https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528226/custom-jwt-based-authentication-for-google-app-engine-using-java

Comment: I tried to look into but I think if I am inside Google's App Engine environment and in the same project, there should be a better way to authenticate the request (secured by oauth2/v4 token) from Standard to Flex.